# In iOS11, you can not get permission through the "ALAssetsLibrary" or "PHPhotoLibrary" command

Tags: ios, alassetslibrary, phphotolibrary

When I try to determine whether the user has permission to open the album, xcode told me that this does not work.

```
let authStatus = ALAssetsLibrary.authorizationStatus()
return authStatus != .restricted && authStatus != .denied
```

xcode remind me

> ‘Use of unresolved identifier 'ALAssetsLibrary’

[xcode screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/21y68.png)

when i try use 'PHPhotoLibrary' on AppDelegate

```
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.


    switch PHPhotoLibrary.authorizationStatus() {
    case PHAuthorizationStatus.NotDetermined: // 用户暂未权限认证
        print("PHAuthorizationStatus.NotDetermined")
        // 权限认证
        PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization { (status:PHAuthorizationStatus) -> Void in
            print(status)
        }
    case PHAuthorizationStatus.Restricted: // APP禁止使用相册权限认证
        print("PHAuthorizationStatus.Restricted")
    case PHAuthorizationStatus.Denied: // 用户拒绝使用相册
        print("PHAuthorizationStatus.Denied")
        print("请进入 设置 -> 隐私 -> 相册 开启权限")
    // 设置-隐私-相册
    case PHAuthorizationStatus.Authorized: // 用户允许使用相册
        print("PHAuthorizationStatus.Authorized")
    }


    return true
}
```

xcode also told me

> Use of unresolved identifier 'PHPhotoLibrary'

Comment: It's deprecated, use `PHPhotoLibrary` instead.

Comment: @WeiJay thank you,i use your method to solve the current problem!

Answer (score 12):

Ok，I have realized what is the answer, add the “import Photos” at the top of the swift file after everything is normal

"PHPhotoLibrary" is used correctly in the following way.

```
func AlbumPermissions() -> Int { // Photos Permissions
switch PHPhotoLibrary.authorizationStatus() {
    
case .notDetermined:// User has not permitted the permission
    print("PHAuthorizationStatus.NotDetermined")
    
    PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization { (status:PHAuthorizationStatus) -> Void in
        print(status)
    }
    
    return 0
case .restricted:// APP reject the permission of Photos
    print("PHAuthorizationStatus.Restricted")
    return 1
case .denied:// Users denied the Photos permission
    print("PHAuthorizationStatus.Denied")
    print("Please go to Setting to turn on the Photos permission.")
    return 2
case .authorized: // User permit the Photos permission.
    print("PHAuthorizationStatus.Authorized")
    return 3
}}
```

Comment: BTW, you can just return the `PHPhotoLibrary.authorizationStatus()` for your function. (if needed)

Comment: The `import Photos` saved my day.